# Update Shared Preferences after restarting application

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I use Shared Preferences to fetch and store a variable, I then fetch that variable across a different class. After I restart the app, the initial variable stored is to be updated by the new one. What I can see is that on quitting the application, I should set my shared preference to be cleared and then again fetch the fetch value.

However, the problem is that even on restart, the shared preference still store the older value and do not update themselves.

Here is the code where I initially save the value

```
protected void onLoginSuccess(String cookieString, String userName) {
    // set cookie and initialize data center.
    mCookieString = cookieString;

     SharedPreferences  settings =getSharedPreferences("cookie",MODE_PRIVATE);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putString("cookie", cookieString);
     editor.commit();
      //editor.apply();

    mDataCenter = new LsApiDataCenter(this, userName);
    mCachedUserData.clear();
      System.out.println("shhhhhhhhhhhh iis original : "+cookieString);
    mSendersObservers.clear();
    mMessageObservers.clear();
    mNotificationObservers.clear();
```

Later, Upon exit I want the shared preference to be cleared and this is how I do it

```
protected void onLogoutSuccess() {
    // clear cookie and data center.
    SharedPreferences   settings =getSharedPreferences("cookie",MODE_PRIVATE);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
     editor.clear().commit();
    mCookieString = null;
    mDataCenter = null;
    mCachedUserData.clear();

    mSendersObservers.clear();
    mMessageObservers.clear();
    mNotificationObservers.clear();
```

Finally, this is  how I fetch them in a completely different class

```
SharedPreferences settings = mMainActivity.getSharedPreferences("cookie", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        count = settings.getString("cookie","");
```

The problem is that the value which I get upon fetching is the old value and not the latest value since i am fetching a value provided by a server via api used when the user logs in. However, I get the old value and the latest value is not fetched.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean on exit? Where exactly are you calling the `onLogoutSuccess()` method? In onPause() or onStop() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to clear the value of cookie variable you can do like this

```
 SharedPreferences  settings =getSharedPreferences("cookie",MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
 editor.putString("cookie", null);
 editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Nope, It doesn't work, I still get the older value as the output upon fetching.